Images on flutter desktop are blurry
I am running Flutter 3.22.1 and I am trying to add an image to the AppBar instead of a text, but for some reason it always shows blurry. Matter of fact any image I add in the application shows blurry.
Here is what I have done:
    AppBar(
      title: Image.asset(
        "assets/images/akshay.png",
        fit: BoxFit.cover,
        filterQuality: FilterQuality.high,
        height: 30,
      ),
    );

And I get

The image is of size 2365 x 652. Not sure how to get this to be clear?
Edit: I am running this on Ubuntu 22.04

Are you running on an emulator or an actual device?

@shimomaru I am running this on Ubuntu 22.04, updated the content.
